# How to autofit columns in datagrid control (and NOT datagridview) in vb.net / c#.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagrid

We have a Windows Application written in VB/C# which has huge number of Windows Forms. All of these forms use "DataGrid" control and not the "DataGridView" control.

We cannot use the `DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode` property since all forms have the "DataGrid" control and NOT the "DataGridView" control.

Can anyone suggest ways to "autofit" columns in `Systems.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` control

Comment: How many DataGrids you have in total?

Comment: I can't even count. There are more than 1000 win-forms. And each of these have atleast 2-3 DataGrids approx.

Comment: Ouch.
I had a similar problem, but with 'just' 450 WinForms and around 550 DataGrids, but I gave myself coupld of weeks and I transform all DGs to DGVs. It's a painfull job, but now it's much better since DGV has a lot better features then DGs.

Comment: 'Just' as you say! Thanks for your input